# React Native: Unable to Display Remote Images in my App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm encountering an issue in my React Native application where I'm unable to display remote images fetched from a URL. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const imageUrl = 'https://example.com/image.jpg';

  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: imageUrl }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've verified that the imageUrl is correct and accessible through a web browser. However, when I run my React Native app, the image doesn't display, and I don't see any error messages.

I've tried various solutions found online, including adjusting the width and height styles, but the issue persists. Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is working. Something has to do with the URL. Can you share the exact url which you are using?